# Distribution of classical point charges on a unit interval

Tags: optimization, physics

Consider $n$ particles in a unit interval. The potential energy between two particles at $x_i$ and $x_j$ is $f(|x_i-x_j|)$. $f$ is a positive-valued, monotonically decreasing convex function. There is hard-wall repulsion between particles and walls at $x=0$ and $x=1$. How are the particles distributed so that the total potential energy is minimized?

From numerical simulation I found that for the same $f$, the particles are distributed on the same curve regardless of the total number.

For $f(r)=r^{-1}$, the positions of particles can be found through [Chebyshev polynomials](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Chebyshev_polynomials#/Roots_and_extrema).

Are there more general results on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One generalization is this: http://emis.ams.org/journals/ETNA/vol.26.2007/pp439-452.dir/pp439-452.pdf

Which generalized to the case where apart from free charges on the [-1,1] interval, there are fixed charges around it in the complex plane. The equilibrium positions correspond the points for near-best rational interpolation with poles at the locations of fixed charges. When these charges recede to infinity, you get the zeros of Chebyshev polynomials, which are optimal for polynomial interpolation.